# Android alarm manager is going off more than once a day

Tags: android

I am working on a simple app. A notification is supposed to fire once a day , the user would click on it and then learn a new word. It seems to be going off multiple times. I have alarm manager set to inexact repeating and an interval of daily. Can anyone help? As far as I can tell it should be working correctly, does it have soemthing to do with how the app exits? When the user leaves the app?

here is a link to it on github:

https://github.com/champrt78/word

Comment: how many number of times it runs ?

Comment: I had been just running it over and over to my phone, I wasn't ever really uninstalling it on my phone before  re-installing it from eclipse ... maybe that has something to do with it? because it seemed as though it would go of at times like: 19:39 , 20:39 , 21:39. Or similar times.  I had uninstalled it last night and hard coded the time for it to go off at 21:53, I then UN-installed the app , re-started my phone , and then re-installed the app , it went off at 21:53 and hasn't since... maybe that was it? I checked it is still running in the background..